# Interpretation of a variable in the regression analysis

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, interpretation, mediation

I have a question regarding the interpretation of my regression analysis. Imagine the following situation: There is a very high (and significant) correlation between variable A and the dependent variable in the correlation matrix.  In the regression analysis, I have multiple other independent variables and variable A is just one of them. In all of the cases Variable A has a lot of influence (high beta) and this is also significant. However there is an exception. Only when I put variable A in combination with a particular variable (Variable X) the influence of variabdrops and it is not significant anymore. So, only when variable X is not taken in the regression variable A is significant and has a lot of predictive power. When variable X is also taken, it is not significant. There is definitely not multicolliniearity involved. Does that mean that the influence of Variable A on the dependent variable works through variable X?

Comment: When you have both A and X in the model, is the effect of X large?

If so, it sounds like you have mediation (the technical name for "works through").  Searching on mediation will yield lots of stuff, both here on CV and more generally. 

If you do some looking and are still unsure, you can edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: The effect of X is indeed very large (high beta, and a very high significance level). However, both variable A and X are already mediating variables. So in the first model I have the control variables, in the second model the independent variable and in model 3 the mediators (variable X and A). I verified the baron and kenny method with several more advanced mediation tests and came up with the same results. If I have instead of variable X another mediating variable, then variable A is also a mediator. Only in combination with variable X, variable A loses its (significant) power in influence.